# How can I add operation symbols (+, *, -, /) to an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I add operation symbols (`+, *, -, /`) to an array in JavaScript? I am trying to get a randomized symbol from an array and I have 4 options: +, *, -, /.

```
var operations = [*, +, -, /]
```

It does not detect it as an array of symbols though.

I am trying to create a webapp for me to practice math. I want to get two random numbers that will get operated (added, multiplied, divided, or subtracted) by a random operation (-, /, *, or +). so the equation becomes totally random, example: 472 * 820 =.

Comment: What do you expect as output here when accessing the array? Strings? Characters? Mathematical operators?

Comment: You can't add _operators_ -- you can add _strings_ that represent those operators, e.g. `let operations = [ '*', '+', '-', '/' ];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to add quote around the symbols as follows -

```js
var operations = ['*', '+', '-', '/'];
console.log(operations);

function getRandom(){
  return operations[Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(4))]
}
// To get a random symbol - 
console.log(getRandom())

// One way to use a random symbol in a given expression would be as -
const num1 = Math.floor(100*Math.random()), num2 = Math.floor(100*Math.random());

const expression = `${num1}${getRandom()}${num2}`
const result = eval(expression)
console.log(result)
```

As you can see, you can use `eval()`, if you are forming an expression string using the way I have shown in the above code snippet. The [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) function evaluates JavaScript code represented as a string.

Comment: Would making the operation symbol a string take away its functionality of being able to make an operation with numbers?

Comment: @WiseEye How do you want to use it to make an operation ?

Comment: I am trying to create a webapp for me to practice math. I want to get two random numbers that will get operated (added, multiplied, divided, or subtracted) by a random operation (-, /, *, or +). so the equation becomes totally random, example: 472 * 820 =.

Comment: @WiseEye Check my edit. It does the thing you are trying to achieve

Comment: Thanks! I will try it out on my project and get back to you in a couple on mins!

Comment: Thanks again! I have now this variable (var result = firstNumber randomOperation secondNumber)... firstNumber is the random first number, secondNumber is the second random number, and  randomOperation is the random symbol you just showed me to obtain. This are all variables, how can I use those variables to get the result?

Comment: @WiseEye You just have to form a string of those variables. You can do it like this - var expression =` ${firstNumber} ${randomOperation} ${secondNumber}` and then find result as var result = eval(expression )

Comment: Sorry, this may be a bit stressfull for you, I am still learning a lot about programming. Is the ${} syntax JQuery? if yes, is there any way to do that without JQuery? If i put the expression into a string then it just becomes a string, just words.

Comment: @WiseEye The  ${} syntax is the template literal. The previous comment expression is the same as -  var expression = firstNumber + randomOperation + secondNumber; and calculating result as var result = eval(expression )

Comment: @WiseEye — you should know that `eval()` is considered _dangerous_. If you `eval(someUserInput)` you are vulnerable to attack. I could form my input into something that would be executed when eval is run on it. I strongly recommend that you _do **not**_ use eval for your application.

Comment: @WiseEye You should make the string in this manner - var result = firstNumber + randomOperation + secondNumber; In your case, the string was  this itself- * "firstNumber randomOperation secondNumber"*. However, we wanted the string to be value of firstNumber, followed by randomOperation, followed by value of secondNumber. For that, use it in the above manner

Comment: Thank you for your patience!! That worked perfectly. (1397.71 / 2295.33 = 0.6089364056584456) I got that. Thanks! I got it by using this ---   var expression = firstNumber + randomOperation + secondNumber;

  var result = eval(expression);

Answer (score 1):

You need quotes around strings.

```js
var operations = ['*', '+', '-', '/'];
var randIdx = Math.random() * operations.length | 0;
var randOp = operations[randIdx];
console.log(randOp);
```

To actually perform random operations, you do not need the operators themselves: you can just generate a random integer from 0-3 and map each integer to an operation yourself.

```js
var rand1 = Math.random() * 50 | 0 + 50, 
    rand2 = Math.random() * 50 | 0 + 50,
    randOp = Math.random() * 4 | 0;
console.log(rand1, ["+", "-", "*", "/"][randOp], rand2, "=");
switch(randOp){
  case 0:
    console.log(rand1 + rand2);
    break;
  case 1:
    console.log(rand1 - rand2);
    break;
  case 2:
    console.log(rand1 * rand2);
    break;
  default:
    console.log(rand1 / rand2);
}
```

Comment: Would making the operation symbol a string take away its functionality of being able to make an operation with numbers?

Comment: @WiseEye How are you trying to use the operators? You probably need to parse it yourself.

Comment: I am trying to create a webapp for me to practice math. I want to get two random numbers that will get operated (added, multiplied, divided, or subtracted) by a random operation (-, /, *, or +). so the equation becomes totally random, example: 472 * 820 =.

Comment: @WiseEye - you've added this explanation as a comment on 3 answers now. It seems this explanation is _necessary_ for people to give reasonable answers to your question, so you should add this explanation to _**the question**_ itself.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer to "How can I add operation symbols (+, *, -, /) to an array in Javascript" is that *you can't do that*.

An operator is a symbol in the language, but it is not a string, number, boolean, or an Object, so it can't be part of a data structure.
You can put some kind of *representation* of an operator in an array, such as a string:
`let operations = [ '*', '+', '-', '/' ];`

There are several pretty good answers, and with your added explanation of your goal I would recommend something that, in some ways, combines some elements from those answers.

You want to *display* two random numbers with the choice of a random operation to create a math problem. Displaying them suggests using string representations of the operators.
However, you also want to perform the operation that the operator represents; that means you have to turn that operator string into a computation in some way. One way is to `switch` on the chosen operator, similar to what [hev1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63021600/17300) does...

```js
let num1 = 839;
let num2 = 195;
let op = '+';

let answer;

switch (op) {
    case '*':
        answer = num1 * num2;
        break;
    case '/':
        answer = num1 / num2;
        break;
    case '+':
        answer = num1 + num2;
        break;
    case '-':
        answer = num1 - num2;
        break;
}
console.log('answer is', answer);
```

But now your array and your computation code have to be kept synchronized.

You can also create a function array like [8HoLoN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63021631/17300) does, but then you have no symbol to display in the page unless you again have a corresponding way to pick both the symbol to display and the operation to perform.

***I*** would create an array of objects, where each object contains the symbol to display *and* a function to perform the operation.

Look in particular at how the answer is calculated at `let answer = ...` and how the operator is displayed in the `console.log` line.

```js
// Here's your array of operators. Each object in the array has
// • an "operator" symbol
// • a calculator to perform that operation.
const operators = [
    {
        'operator' : '*',
        'calc' : (a, b) => a * b
    },
    {
        'operator' : '/',
        'calc' : (a, b) => a / b
    },
    {
        'operator' : '+',
        'calc' : (a, b) => a + b
    },
    {
        'operator' : '-',
        'calc' : (a, b) => a - b
    },
];

let num1 = 296;
let num2 = 138;
let op = operators[getRandomIntInclusive(0, operators.length - 1)];

let answer = op.calc(num1, num2);
console.log(num1, op.operator, num2, '=', answer);


/* random int function from MDN
https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random#Getting_a_random_integer_between_two_values_inclusive
*/
function getRandomIntInclusive(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. `*` `/` `+` `-` are operators of the JS language and then you can't reference them as objects in a array.

If what you want is make dynamic random operation, you should use function.

```js
const operators = [
    (a, b) => a + b,
    (a, b) => a * b,
    (a, b) => a - b,
    (a, b) => a / b
];
const a = 2, b = 3;

const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3.9);// between [0;4[
const res = operators[rand](a, b);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: I am trying to create a webapp for me to practice math. I want to get two random numbers that will get operated (added, multiplied, divided, or subtracted) by a random operation (-, /, *, or +). so the equation becomes totally random, example: 472 * 820 =.